# View the live log in linux

Tags: 14.04, bash, scripts, log, watch-command

I want to See the Live log from the Log file which is being used within the Script.

**i have script which makes VPN connection to CISCO VPN Server and then COpy the files to the Remote Location. for having a list of files which was sent , within my VPN Copy Script , i am also making the log files and the LOG file location is in the `tmp` directory. my `VPN copy script` is working really fine without any issue.**

but now what i am trying to do is i run this command

```
watch tail -n 15 /tmp/vpn.log
tail -f /tmp/vpn.log
```

over the terminal and wants to see the Live log of the log files , and in this log file i will see the Information about the file transfer to remote location. but my problem is when i run

```
watch tail -n 15 /tmp/vpn.log
tail -f /tmp/vpn.log
```

these commands and then run my Script then my files doestn transfer to the remote location and when i am not running `tail` command over the log files then my `VPN copy script` works without any issue.

so basically want that i can view the live log and my `vpn copy script` also can works.

can someone please help me ?

thanks

Comment: Unless you haved used any locking mechanism you should be able to read the file, how are you saving the logs within your script ? do you get any error message ? btw when you do `tail` your file is opened for reading, unless it is not opned for writing there would be no race condition or other problem..

Comment: `LOGFILE="/tmp/vpn.log"`

`echo -n `date` >> `$LOGFILE && echo "   [INFO] The transfer for file $FILE with a size of $FS  ist starting now..." >> $LOGFILE``

That's how i created the log file

Comment: Is checking the output of `tail -f [...]` in another terminal fine?

Comment: i can see the output with `tail -f [......]` and the output is fine but only my script doesn't do what script is supposed to do.

Comment: You can do it together : `printf ""$(date)"  [INFO] The transfer for file "$FILE" with a size of "$FS" ist starting now...\n" >>"$LOGFILE"` ..also do you get any message ? try updaing the file manually while running `tail -f`, what happens ?

Answer (score 1):

Running `watch tail -n 15 /tmp/vpn.log` / `tail -f /tmp/vpn.log` in the script stops its execution, because the when executing `watch tail -n 15 /tmp/vpn.log` / `tail -f /tmp/vpn.log` the shell is busy running `watch tail -n 15 /tmp/vpn.log` / `tail -f /tmp/vpn.log` themselves;

Generally a solution could be running the process as a background job or running the process separately from the current shell by any mean, however since you need to see the output of the process in question, a nice way to do this would be to run it in a new `gnome-terminal` instance:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
touch /tmp/vpn.log
gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "echo $$ > pid; tail -f /tmp/vpn.log"'
echo "Starting to output to /tmp/vpn.log"
echo line1 >> /tmp/vpn.log
sleep 1
echo line2 >> /tmp/vpn.log
sleep 1
echo line3 >> /tmp/vpn.log
kill -15 "$(< pid)"
rm pid
exit 0
```

- `touch /tmp/vpn.log`: creates a 0-length file named "vpn.log" in `/tmp` if not existing, or updates `/tmp/vpn.log`'s access and modification time if existing; this is done to ensure that `tail -f [...]` won't exit on error;
- `gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "echo $$ > pid; tail -f /tmp/vpn.log"'`: spawns a `gnome-terminal` instance and spawns a `bash` instance inside the `gnome-terminal` instance, which outputs its PID to a file named "pid" and runs `tail -f /tmp/vpn.log`;
- `kill -15 "$(< pid)"`: sends a SIGTERM signal to the `bash` instance running inside the `gnome-terminal` instance;
- `rm pid`: removes "pid";

[image: screenshot]

Comment: HI @kos ,

This `touch log` , i am assuming that the `LOG` is the log file Path in my System.

thanks

Comment: @kunal Yes, you should replace it with the actual path to your log file

Comment: thanks ! I give a try to it and then let you know the result.

Comment: Hi @kos,

i just again wants to clear that my Log file is updated every time when my script runs and my log script is different which is actually copying the files to remote location and i am only creating and echoing the information which i am copying like the file id and file size.
so with my log files , i need to only monitor the log files that i can see the last copied file

Comment: @kunal It's hard to understand what you're saying without seeing the script, can you add it to your question?

Comment: i have updated my question

Comment: @kunal From what I understand, your log file is kept locally in `/tmp`; so this should work. Simply add `touch /tmp/log` and `gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "echo $$ > pid; tail -f /tmp/log"'` to the start of the script connecting to the VPN server; remove any other `tail -f [...]` command in the script, which are blocking its execution and add `kill -15 "$(< pid)"` and `rm pid` at the end of the script.